# How can I filter nested object in a complex array in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

After handle the response data I got an array like below in React-Native

```
[{
  "children": [],
  "data": {
    "catCd": "C000000146",
    "catGrpCd": "CG00000135",
    "catNames": [Array],
    "catNm": "Game Design",
    "parentCatCd": "C000000143",
    "parentCatCdPath": "C000000143.C000000146",
    "usedFlag": true
  },
  "hasChildren": false,
  "id": "C000000146",
  "key": "C000000146",
  "sortOrder": 3
}, {
  "children": ["C000000144", "C000000145", "C000000146"],
  "data": {
    "catCd": "C000000143",
    "catGrpCd": "CG00000135",
    "catNames": [Array],
    "catNm": "Design",
    "parentCatCd": null,
    "parentCatCdPath": "C000000143",
    "usedFlag": true
  },
  "hasChildren": true,
  "id": "C000000143",
  "key": "C000000143",
  "sortOrder": 1
}, {
  "children": ["C000000166"],
  "data": {
    "catCd": "C000000144",
    "catGrpCd": "CG00000135",
    "catNames": [Array],
    "catNm": "3D & Animation",
    "parentCatCd": "C000000143",
    "parentCatCdPath": "C000000143.C000000144",
    "usedFlag": true
  },
  "hasChildren": true,
  "id": "C000000144",
  "key": "C000000144",
  "sortOrder": 1
}, {
  "children": [],
  "data": {
    "catCd": "C000000166",
    "catGrpCd": "CG00000135",
    "catNames": [Array],
    "catNm": "Depth1",
    "parentCatCd": "C000000144",
    "parentCatCdPath": "C000000143.C000000144.C000000166",
    "usedFlag": true
  },
  "hasChildren": false,
  "id": "C000000166",
  "key": "C000000166",
  "sortOrder": 1
}, {
  "children": [],
  "data": {
    "catCd": "C000000145",
    "catGrpCd": "CG00000135",
    "catNames": [Array],
    "catNm": "Design Tools",
    "parentCatCd": "C000000143",
    "parentCatCdPath": "C000000143.C000000145",
    "usedFlag": true
  },
  "hasChildren": false,
  "id": "C000000145",
  "key": "C000000145",
  "sortOrder": 2
}, {
  "children": [],
  "data": {
    "catCd": "C000000167",
    "catGrpCd": "CG00000135",
    "catNames": [Array],
    "catNm": "Design 01",
    "parentCatCd": null,
    "parentCatCdPath": "C000000167",
    "usedFlag": true
  },
  "hasChildren": false,
  "id": "C000000167",
  "key": "C000000167",
  "sortOrder": 1
}, {
  "children": ["C000000143", "C000000167"],
  "data": null,
  "hasChildren": true,
  "id": "C000000095",
  "key": "C000000095",
  "sortOrder": 0
}]
```

Finally I want to filter and get all the element that has parentCatCD : null. Because I am new to react and have tried a lots but nothing works. (map, filter, some, etc ...), I always got undefined is not an object error when I try to filter them.

How can I solve this problem?

My code:

```
  function filterData(arr: any) {
    let newArray = arr.filter(function(item:any){
      return item.data['parentCatCd'] == null;
   }).map(function({data} : {data:any}){
       return {data};
   });
  }
```

error : null is not an object (evaluating 'item.data['parentCatCd'])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so you can try this.

```
let filteredData = response.filter(e => e.data && e.data.parentCatCd === null);
```

This will return you that data where the parentCatCd is null.

Comment: thats worked ! thanks, but can you tell me what is wrong and why this is worked please

Comment: Before checking if parentCatCd is null, you need to make sure that data object is not null , thats why its **e.data && e.data.prentCatCd**. You were directly checking for parentCatCd, without checking if data is null. Thus you were getting null is not an object error.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your data is in variable **response**. The problem with your array is you have your last **data** field as **null**. So the normal **filter** method check will get an error. You can try something like bellow.

```
let newResponse = response.filter((res) => res.data && res.data.parentCatCd === null).map(({data}) => data);
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your array structure, Before reading `parentCatCd` you need to check `item.data` is `null` or not, because some items in your array has `data` property with `null` value, like this:

```js
let data= [{ "children": [], "data": { "catCd": "C000000146", "catGrpCd": "CG00000135", "catNames": [Array], "catNm": "Game Design", "parentCatCd": "C000000143", "parentCatCdPath": "C000000143.C000000146", "usedFlag": true }, "hasChildren": false, "id": "C000000146", "key": "C000000146", "sortOrder": 3 }, { "children": ["C000000144", "C000000145", "C000000146"], "data": { "catCd": "C000000143", "catGrpCd": "CG00000135", "catNames": [Array], "catNm": "Design", "parentCatCd": null, "parentCatCdPath": "C000000143", "usedFlag": true }, "hasChildren": true, "id": "C000000143", "key": "C000000143", "sortOrder": 1 }, { "children": ["C000000166"], "data": { "catCd": "C000000144", "catGrpCd": "CG00000135", "catNames": [Array], "catNm": "3D & Animation", "parentCatCd": "C000000143", "parentCatCdPath": "C000000143.C000000144", "usedFlag": true }, "hasChildren": true, "id": "C000000144", "key": "C000000144", "sortOrder": 1 }, { "children": [], "data": { "catCd": "C000000166", "catGrpCd": "CG00000135", "catNames": [Array], "catNm": "Depth1", "parentCatCd": "C000000144", "parentCatCdPath": "C000000143.C000000144.C000000166", "usedFlag": true }, "hasChildren": false, "id": "C000000166", "key": "C000000166", "sortOrder": 1 }, { "children": [], "data": { "catCd": "C000000145", "catGrpCd": "CG00000135", "catNames": [Array], "catNm": "Design Tools", "parentCatCd": "C000000143", "parentCatCdPath": "C000000143.C000000145", "usedFlag": true }, "hasChildren": false, "id": "C000000145", "key": "C000000145", "sortOrder": 2 }, { "children": [], "data": { "catCd": "C000000167", "catGrpCd": "CG00000135", "catNames": [Array], "catNm": "Design 01", "parentCatCd": null, "parentCatCdPath": "C000000167", "usedFlag": true }, "hasChildren": false, "id": "C000000167", "key": "C000000167", "sortOrder": 1 }, { "children": ["C000000143", "C000000167"], "data": null, "hasChildren": true, "id": "C000000095", "key": "C000000095", "sortOrder": 0 }]

let result = data.filter(item => item.data && item.data.parentCatCd == null).map(({data})=> data)
console.log(result)
```